# Tag merge request [death-knight] -> [world-of-warcraft]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-merging

Please can a mod merge [death-knight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-knight) into [world-of-warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft), [death-knight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-knight) is rather useless, and only applies to a few questions.

Comment: There's a game called [Death Knight](http://itunes.apple.com/hk/app/death-knight/id369634120?mt=8) for iOS, so I don't think these should ever be merged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In line with our `tf2-class` tags I have renamed the tag [wow-death-knight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wow-death-knight). I'm not aware if other tags need the same treatement.

So long as a tag has two questions in 6 months *it's enough questions to justify the existence of that tag.*

We are not running out of tags. Stop worrying about low-count tags.

Comment: I'm not worrying, just clearing up clutter.

Comment: @QAdley I think your definition of "clutter" is a bit too broad.

Comment: Hence I raised the issue here rather than engaging my auto-burninator. Thanks for clearing it up.